# Surprising behaviour with an unordered_set of pairs

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set, stdset

How can the `unordered_set` can hold both `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` if they have the same hash value?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct PairHash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator()(pair<T1, T2> const &p) const
    {
        size_t hash_first = hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        size_t hash_second = hash<T2>{}(p.second);
        size_t hash_combined = hash_first ^ hash_second;
        
        cout << hash_first << ", " << hash_second << ", " << hash_combined << endl;
        
        return hash_combined;    
    }
};

int main()
{
    unordered_set<pair<int, int>, PairHash> map;
    map.insert({0, 1});
    map.insert({1, 0});
    
    cout << map.size() << endl;

    for (auto& entry : map) {
        cout << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 1
1, 0, 1
2
1, 0
0, 1
```

[Link to onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/HmNAHYoaT).

Comment: Why shouldn't it be able to hold different objects with the same hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unordered_set` can hold one instance of any unique data-value; it is not limited to only holding data-values with unique hash-values.  In particular, when two data-values are different (according to their `==` operator) but both hash to the same hash-value, the `unordered_set` will make arrangements to hold both of them regardless, usually at a slightly reduced efficiency (since any hash-based lookups for either of them will internally hash to a data structure that holds both of them, which the unordered_set's lookup-code will have to iterate over until it finds the one it is looking for)

Comment: Btw for an amusing party trick, try changing your `operator()` to just always return 0, and watch how that affects the `unordered_set`'s performance as you add more and more different values to the set :)